# Pattern for choosing behaviour based on the types present in a collection derived objects

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, virtual-functions

I have an collection of objects which represents a model of a system. Each of these objects derives from a base class which represents the abstract "component". I would like to be able to look at the system and choose certain behaviours based on what components are present and in what order.

For the sake of argument, let's call the base class `Component` and the actual components `InputFilter`, `OutputFilter` and `Processor`. Systems that we can deal with are ones with a `Processor` and one or both filters. The actual system has more types and more complex interaction between them, but I think this will do for now.

I can see two "simple" ways to handle this situation with a `marshalComponentSettings()` function which takes one of the collections and works out how to most efficiently set up each node. This may require modifying inputs in certain ways or splitting them up differently, so it's not quite as simple as just implementing a virtual `handleSettings()` function per component.

- The first is to report a enumerated type from each class using a pure virtual function and use those to work out what to do, `dynamic_cast`'ing where needed to access component specific options.

  ```
  enum CompType {
      INPUT_FILTER,
      OUTPUT_FILTER,
      PROCESSOR
  }

  void marshal(Settings& stg)
  {
      if (comps[0].type() == INPUT_FILTER)
          setUpInputFilter(stg); //maybe modified the stg, or provides other feedback of what was done

      // something similar for outputs

      setUpProcessor(stg);
  }
  ```
- The second is to `dynamic_cast` to anything that might be an option in this function and use the success of that or not (as well as maybe the cast object if needed) to determine what to do.

  ```
  void marshal(Settings& stg)
  {
      if (InputFilter* filter = dynamic_cast<InputFilter*>(comp[0]))
          setUpInputFilter(stg); //maybe modified the stg, or provides other feedback of what was done

      // something similar for outputs

     setUpProcessor(stg);
  }
  ```

It seems that the first is the most efficient way (don't need to speculatively test each object to find out what it is), but even that doesn't quite seem right (maybe due to the annoying details of how those devices affect each other leaking into the general marshaling code).

Is there a more elegant way to handle this situation than a nest of conditionals determining behaviour? Or even a name for the situation or pattern?

Comment: 1st thing that comes to mind is the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html).

Comment: You should write your code for ease of understanding by humans first and foremost, and worry about code efficiency only if it becomes a problem. Even though an algorithm that tests each object to find out its type will run in O(n) time (or even O(n^2) time if you have to compare it with every other object), that is not going to be a problem unless you have many thousands of components to compare in your system.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: that looks like a very promising "strategy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario seems an ideal candidate for the **[visitor design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html)**, with the following roles (see UML schema in the link):

- objectStructure:  your model, aka collection of `Component`
- element:  your `Component` base class
- concreteElementX:  your actual components (`InputFilter`, `OutputFilter`, `Processor`, ...)
- visitor:  the abstract family of algorithms that has to manage your model as a consistent set of elements.
- concreteVisitorA:  your configuration process.

**Main advantages:**

Your configuration/set-up corresponds to the design pattern's intent: *an operation to be performed on the elements of an object structure*.  Conversely, this pattern allows you to take into consideration the order and kind of elements encountered during the traversal, as visitors can be ***stateful***.

One positive side effect is that the visitor pattern will give your desing the flexibility to easily add new processes/algortihms with similar traversals but different purpose (for example: pricing of the system, material planning,  etc...)

```
class Visitor; 
class Component {
public:
    virtual void accept(class Visitor &v) = 0;
};
class InputFilter: public Component {
public:
    void accept(Visitor &v) override;  // calls the right visitor function
};
...
class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(InputFilters *c) = 0;  // one virtual funct for each derived component.
    virtual void visit(Processor *c) = 0;
    ...
};
void InputFilter::accept(Visitor &v)
{ v.visit(this); }
...
class SetUp : public Visitor {
private: 
    bool hasProcessor; 
    int  impedenceFilter;  
    int  circuitResistance; 
public: 
    void visit(InputFilters *c) override;  
    void visit(Processor *c) override; 
    ... 
};
```

**Challenge:**

The main challenge you'll have for the visitor, but with other alternatives as well, is that the setup can change the configuration itself (replacing component ? change of order), so that you have to take care of keeping a consitent iterator on the container while making sure not to process items several time.

The best approach depends on the type of the container, and on the kind of changes that your setup is doing. But you'll certainly need some flags to see which element was already processed, or a temporary container (either elements processed or elements remaining to be processed).

In any case, as the visitor is a class, it can also encapsulate any such state data in private members.